# imshow error in line 15 MatLab 2017a

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm trying to display an image with matlab. From what I understand, the imshow function is supposed to do this, but for some reason it's not working. When I try to use it in the matlab interpreter in the terminal nothing happens: Can someone tell me why I have error in line 15(imshow).

```
clc
clear all
close all

%% reference image

[filename, filepath]=uigetfile('*.*','Select reference image');
filedir=strcat(filepath,'\',filename);
images=imread(filedir);
resize=256;
img_ref=imresize(images,[resize resize],'bilinear');

figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(img_ref);
title('Reference Image')
```

Comment: Do you really want to resize to a 2x2 pixel image? Also, you don't set `img` in this example code.

Comment: Show the error message please